# How did you remove a radiator fan in a 2011 Honda Accord? I removed the two screw and harness and it’s supposedly to just slide out but won’t budge

Tags: honda, alternator, accord, fan

I’m changing out my alternator and gave to remove the radiator fan ti do so. I undid the screws and harness. It wont budge.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This is an electric fan, correct? Did you try pushing the top of the fan back towards the engine first, then trying to pull it out? I think there is a lip at the bottom of the fan which holds it to the radiator, but not sure. I'm familiar with Honda fans, but not yours specifically. I'm aware of tabs at the bottom of the fan(s) which fit into slots at the bottom. At least that seems quite common on other Honda models I've worked on.

Comment: Yes I’ve tried that. I know it probably something simple. I just can’t figure it out.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is the pins (saw this in images :o) at the bottom of the shroud may be stuck in their rubber grommets. It may just take a little bit of gentle persuasion from the bottom (near the grommets) to get the pins to come free.